# Why is jslint reporting Unexpected 'variable'

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have the following code

```
/*globals define,console*/
define(
  function(param) {
    'use strict';
    var v1 = v1 || {};
    console.log(v1);
  }
);
```

and jslint reports:

```
jslint:accessibility2.js:5:18:Unexpected 'v1'.

jslint: ignored 0 errors.
```

I wonder why jslint doesn't like the `var v1 = v1 || {};` stuff?

Comment: Don't you want `var v1 = param || {}`?  Your code effectively assigns `v1 = {}`.

Comment: nope, if v1 is already defined I don't want to overwrite it... and if it doesn't exist I want to initilize it to {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var v1; 
v1 = v1 || {};
```

Should do the trick.
Why?
You use the v1 on the right side before you declare it on the left side.